# 1 level deep in a SOQL query

Tags: soql

I can't choose my last file by record Id (this file was uploaded for this record). How can I do that by SOQL query?

```
conVersion = [SELECT Id FROM ContentVersion WHERE (Select LinkedEntityId from ContentDocumentId_r =: recId) order by CreatedDate DESC limit 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite your query. Your query will be like

```
ContentDocumentLink cdl = [SELECT ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId =: recId order by CreatedDate DESC limit 1];
```

and then second query

```
for(ContentVersion cv: [select Id, title, ContentDocumentId from ContentVersion where ContentDocumentId in: cdl.ContentDocumentId]){
        system.debug( cv);
}
```

or you can merge both query in single query as well.

Comment: But I need ContentVersion, not ContentDocumentLink. My ContentVersion.Id is in image URL.

Comment: @MichaelLev19 check my updated answer.

Comment: Downvote. Can you please explain?